# How to use a static enum in another class in typescript

Tags: typescript

Using this question and answer as a reference, [Can you set a static enum inside of a TypeScript class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509056/can-you-set-a-static-enum-inside-of-a-typescript-class), I created an enum and made it a static property in my class as follows

```
/* Input.ts */
enum INPUT_TYPE { TEXT, RADIO, CHECKBOX }
export class Input {
    static INPUT_TYPE = INPUT_TYPE;
    readonly inputType: INPUT_TYPE;

    constructor (inputType: INPUT_TYPE) {
        this.inputType = inputType;
    }
}
```

Yes, this is a basic class, used as an example.

I have a second class in another file that needs to use it.

```
import {Input} from "./Input";
/* InputLabel.ts */
export class InputLabel extends Input {
    readonly label: string;

    constructor(label:string, inputType: Input.INPUT_TYPE) {
        super(inputType);
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and have the *"Language & Frameworks" -> TypeScript: "TypeScript version:" custom* pointing to my current version, which is 2.0.2.  IntelliJ is complaining to me and stating that it cannot find the namespace 'Input'.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import {Input} from "./Input";`?

Comment: Yes. I fixed it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to work this way, just write

```
/* Input.ts */
export class Input {
    readonly inputType: Input.INPUT_TYPE;

    constructor (inputType: Input.INPUT_TYPE) {
        this.inputType = inputType;
    }
}
export namespace Input {
    export enum INPUT_TYPE { TEXT, RADIO, CHECKBOX }
}
```